Necessary and sufficient condition for a finite rooted tree to be a redundancy tree
Let $S$ be a consistent finite set of axioms in some first-order language $L$. Recall the definition of an axiom $A$ in $S$ being redundant: $S$ - $\{A\}$ can prove $A$. Now, it can happen that even after one redundant axiom is removed from an axiom set, there are still more redundant axioms. In fact, we can form a labeled rooted tree for $S$ by a recursive procedure. We start with the root, which is labeled with $S$. If $S$ has no redundant axioms, then stop. Otherwise, if $S$ has $n$ redundant axioms $A_1,...,A_n$ , then create $n$ successor nodes, and label the $m$-th node with $S - \{A_m\}$, where $1 \leq m \leq n$. Now, repeat this procedure for each of the nodes. We end up with a finite labeled rooted tree, which I call the redundancy tree associated with $S$.
My question is, what is a useful necessary and sufficient condition for a finite rooted tree $T$ to be a redundancy tree for some finite axiom set $S$? I conjecture that the following condition is both necessary and sufficient: Every node other than the root has strictly less children than its parent. Is that so? If not, is the criteria at least necessary or at least sufficient?

The condition is clearly necessary, but it is not sufficient. If root has $n$ children and depth 1 nodes have $n-1$  children, the subtrees starting at depth $2$ must be 2 by 2 isomorphic.
